# how to split the screen horizontally across the screen

Tags: android, orientation, android-linearlayout

Right now it splits vertically...I want it to split horizontally. I've looked at everyone else that says theirs cuts horizontally and I can't tell the difference...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your orientation to `vertical`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:layout_weight=".1" >
 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:layout_weight=".1" >
</LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why does changing the orientation to vertical make that possible...?

Comment: you want to split the screen one linear down to other so it will possible by setting the orientation to vertical

Answer (score 1):

you should make the sub Views `fill_parent

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this will create 2 L`LinearLayout` objects side by side.

if you want to create the one ontop of the other, you should make the `android:orientation="vertical"` instead

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There won't be change with this code. change the orientation for the parent linear layout to vertical

Comment: @Ramkiran, The author of the question wants to split screen horizontally, please read the question carefully.